# error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist after migrating to android x

Tags: android, build.gradle

I have migrated to android x, Included `google()`repo to build.gradle(project's) and `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'` to app's build.gradle, After migrating to android x can not install support libraries through sdk manager. how can i solve this? I have visited similar questions and no suitable answer for my case.

Comment: After migrating to `AndroidX`, there is no need to use `support` library. As `AndroidX` is the modern version of `support` library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `AndroidX` version of `appcompat`

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

Instead of

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

Comment: When I use that I get a problem to use getActivity() method inside a fragment to pass the context of the containing Activity. I get an error (FragmentActivity cannot be converted to AppCompatActivity) and thought I should use the later one. Regarding the stated question your answer is right. I am marking it accepted for others to refer to it. If you have any clue please help?

Comment: Should use `AndroidX` version of `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity` instead of `support` one `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`

Comment: I am using `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` because my class extends `Fragment` not `FragmentActiviy`. here is the full error message **error: incompatible types: FragmentActivity cannot be converted to AppCompatActivity
**

Comment: No, I told about `Activity` containing `Fragment`. Could you please add details in another post so that i can check. It's hard to tell about the problem without checking code. Hope you understand. Thanks

Comment: I am about to post another question with code details. I have to wait for some minutes. I will leave a link here in a comment. />  The Activity containing the fragment is an `Appcompat`  like `public class NearActivity extends AppCompatActivity `